# External monitor wired to Nvidia card not working on 20.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi, 20.04

So, I've got this weird Nvidia + Intel combination, where HDMI is wired to Nvidia card, so I can't use HDMI without switching to Nvidia driver. When I was using 19.10, it was as simple as opening Nvidia Settings and enabling `Nvidia (Perofrmance mode)` in PRIME Profiles. But now it doesn't work! If I switch the GPUs it doesn't enable the screen. It doesn't even show nvidia-specific settings which were there earlier, like GPU frequencies, connected monitors, all that stuff. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Here is `lshw -c video` output:

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b4080000-b40fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 630
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:133 memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

`lspci` reports I'm using Nvidia driver:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 [8086:591b] (rev 04)
    DeviceName: Intel Kabylake HD Graphics GT2
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HD Graphics 630 [103c:836b]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [10de:1c8d] (rev a1)
    DeviceName: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [103c:836b]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Software and updates window tells me same thing: I'm running `nvidia-driver-440`. What is broken here and how do I fix it?

UPD: It wasn't an upgrade from older system, I made a clean install

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the workaround. It works! but a small correction - There is no 's' in 'driver'

so you do:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-435
```

Answer (score 0):

So, as a workaround, one can downgrade, it solves the issue. For example, to downgrade to v435:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-435
```